# getting a javascript in php using a form : the result is empty

Tags: javascript, php, forms, http-post, transfer

I need to get the end position of an object after it has been dragged and droped.  The drag and drop works fine but I cannot get the js variable in my php.    I use a form (hidden input) to harvest the value of the variable but the $_POST remains empty.

precision : I do not want to use Ajax nor cookies

I am ashamed to post such a simple question, this is my first attempt to use some javascript...

I oversimplified my code to try and isolate the issue and it looks like I have missed something basic in the transfer between javascript and php.  I have read plenty of stuff, including on stackoverflow, but nothing that helped me to understand better (actually the solution I try and implement was picked out of stackoverflow...)```

Here is my oversimplied code:

in profil.php

```
if(isset($_POST['click_x'])){
   $position = $_POST['pos'];
   info($position, 900, 800, red);
}
?>
<script src="essai.js"></script>
<form action="profil.php" method="post">
   <input type="image" src="<?php echo $image;?>" name="click">
   <input type="hidden" name="position" value="" id="position">
</from>
```

in essai

```
var pos = document.getElementById('position');
pos.value="Hello";
```

Comment: You can't do that without ajax or submitting the form. Javascript runs in the browser of the client and php on the server (once when the script is called). Therefore you need to find a way to send the changed value to the server. This is what Ajax is made for. You could also insert the pos value in a hidden form field and submit this. If you do this you have to refer to the input field name and NOT the js object name. So in this case use $_POST['position'] in php.

Comment: Typo: `</from>` should be `</form>`